# Pair Rx Sequences with one sequence as the master who controls when a new output is published

Tags: system.reactive

I'd like to pair two sequences D and A with Reactive Extensions in .NET. The resulting sequence R should pair D and A in a way that whenever new data appears on D, it is paired with the latest value from A as visualized in the following diagram:

```
D-1--2---3---4---
A---a------b-----
R----2---3---4---
     a   a   b
```

CombineLatest or Zip does not exactly what I want. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Latest Rx beta has WithLatestFrom method. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/WithLatestFrom.cs

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`Observable.MostRecent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229751(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
var R = A.Publish(_A => D.SkipUntil(_A).Zip(_A.MostRecent(default(char)), Tuple.Create));
```

Replace `char` with whatever the element type of your `A` observable.

Conceptually, the query above is the same as the following query.

```
var R = D.SkipUntil(A).Zip(A.MostRecent(default(char)), Tuple.Create));
```

The problem with this query is that subscribing to `R` subscribes to `A` twice. This is undesirable behavior.  In the first (better) query above, `Publish` is used to avoid subscribing to `A` twice. It takes a mock of `A`, called `_A`, that you can subscribe to many times in the lambda passed to `Publish`, while only subscribing to the real observable `A` once.

Comment: Wow, that works! Thanks! The usage of publish is not clear to me yet, can you elaborate on it a bit more? This overload does not return an IConnectableObservable, right?

Comment: @RockingChair I expanded on the comments about `Publish`.